# Trying to understand a proof of Kolmogorov's zero-one law

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand a proof of the Kolmogorov's zero-one law. The proof is as follows:

> Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and
> $\{X_i,i\geq 1\}$ be independent random variables. Suppose that
> $\sigma_\infty$ is the tail $\sigma$-algebra of $\{X_i:i\geq 1\}$ and
> let $E\in \sigma_\infty$ be any element.
>
> Since $X_n$ is independent of $\sigma(X_{n+1},\cdots)$ for all
> $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $X_n$ is independent of $\sigma_\infty$ for all
> $n\in\mathbb{N}$ which implies that $\sigma (X_1,X_2,\cdots)$ is
> independent of $\sigma_\infty$. But $\sigma_\infty \subseteq \sigma
> (X_1,X_2,\cdots)$ which implies that $\sigma_\infty$ and
> $\sigma_\infty$ are independent. Therefore,
> $\mathbb{P}(E)=\mathbb{P}(E\cap E)=\mathbb{P}(E)\mathbb{P}(E)$ which
> implies that $\mathbb{P}(E)\in \{0,1\}$.

---

**My question is:** I understand why $X_n$ is independent of $\sigma_\infty$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, but why this implies that $\sigma (X_1,X_2,\cdots)$ is independent of $\sigma_\infty$.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Are you familiar with $\pi-\lambda$ systems? (Dynkin lemma)

Comment: @DominikKutek Yes!

Comment: It's a standard application of Dynkin lemma to show, that if $\mathcal A_1,\mathcal A_2 \subset \Sigma$ are independent $\pi-$systems, then also $\sigma(\mathcal A_1), \sigma(\mathcal A_2)$ are independent (i.e. $\sigma$-fields generated by $\mathcal A_1,\mathcal A_2$ respectively). From independence of $\{X_i\}_i$ it follows that for any $n$, $\mathcal G_n := \sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$ is independent of $\sigma_{\infty}$. Hence, also the $\pi-$system $\mathcal A = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal G_n$ is independent of $\sigma_{\infty}$ and by the above, so is $\sigma(X_1,...) = \sigma(\mathcal A)$.